# Screen locking does not work after upgrade

Tags: 13.10, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I'm using Xscreensaver. I replaced gnome-screensaver with it. Made such link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command
```

However, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> does nothing even after I replaced actual command. 
But running `xscreensaver-command -lock` inside terminal locks screen fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Dash search for keyboard

[image]

Then go to shortcuts tab

[image]

Under System menu go to lock screen and change the associated shortcut to a new One.

[image]

on Custom Shortcuts click on + and enter the command xscreensaver-command and associated it the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I made custom shortcut, but locking does not work anyway except `xscreensaver-command -lock` typed in terminal. Also, I have entry `xscreensaver -nosplash` inside Startup Applications, if someone suspects that I don't have it. Anyway, thanks for your try.

Comment: have you made the custom shortcut with the command `xscreensaver-command -lock` ?

Comment: Yes. I should relogin after that, and now it works!

Comment: @Danatela Ok good. Glad to be able to help. wish you nice time